# How can Material-UI's Dialog allow interaction behind the dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, draggable

I am using [Material-UI](https://v3.material-ui.com/) in my **React** app, and I have a `Dialog` that appears over several form elements after I click a button.

I also have that dialog set to allow it to be dragged using [react-draggable](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/#draggable-dialog).

When the dialog is showing, *none of the form elements behind it are ale to be accessed*. I realize it intuitively makes sense to block interaction with the elements behind the dialog.

However, I am trying to figure out how to have the dialog showing, and yet still being able to edit the form elements behind it.

Code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fdypj):

**Does anyone know if it's possible to show a MaterialUI Dialog and still be able to interact with form elements behind the dialog (ie, when the dialog is dragged away)?**

Comment: Don't fight the control, try to find one that works better; maybe a toast in the footer that the user can manage while they fill in form fields on the page itself? Need to know more about what's in the dialog? You can remove the overlay under the dialog using css, but I'd suggest against it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The dialog was meant to block all other interaction so the user can focus on its contents. Anyway, I found one solution, probably not the better but is working here, the code is this:

```
<Dialog
  hideBackdrop // Disable the backdrop color/image
  disableEnforceFocus // Let the user focus on elements outside the dialog
  style={{ position: 'initial' }} // This was the key point, reset the position of the dialog, so the user can interact with other elements
  disableBackdropClick // Remove the backdrop click (just to be sure)
  ...
>
  ...
</Dialog>
```

[Here a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nin7e?file=/demo.js:1154-2072)

Comment: This is perfect. I hadn't realized that the Material-UI Modal props applied to the Dialog's also, but in retrospect, this makes sense. And your style trick - as you mentioned - is *key*! Thank you! Answer accepted.

Comment: Good that I could help you!

Comment: position initial throws out the styling of the popout to appear at end of content rather than the intended overlay

Comment: pass disableScrollLock={true} incase if you also want to scroll content behind the dialog

Comment: @FernandoGomes when I apply this code it works. but the dialog box appears on top center of the website. do u know how to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, and without too much trouble! When the Dialog is opened, its root container is a div with a class of `MuiDialog-root`, spawned directly in your `<body>`. Instead of putting the react-draggable component around the dialog's `PaperComponent`, we put it around the entire dialog:

```
<Draggable 
  handle={'[class*="MuiDialog-root"]'} 
  cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
    <Dialog 
      // Styling goes here
     > 
     ... // Dialog contents
    </Dialog>
</Draggable>
```

Then, it's necessary to style the Dialog a little. We need to make sure to disable the backdrop, then bring the container size down so that when we click behind it, we are actually selecting other components:

```
<Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    disableEnforceFocus // Allows other things to take focus
    hideBackdrop  // Hides the shaded backdrop
    disableBackdropClick  // Prevents backdrop clicks
    PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
    style={{
        top: '30%', // Position however you like
        left: '30%',
        height: 'fit-content',  // Ensures that the dialog is 
        width: 'fit-content',   // exactly the same size as its contents
    }}
    >
...
</Dialog>
```

Note the `PaperComponent` property. As per the [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#draggable-dialog) on draggable dialogs, this refers to the surface that holds the dialog contents. However, instead of wrapping the paper in a `<Draggable>`, we need to create this component for styling. If we don't, the PaperComponent will have large, obnoxious margins and won't fit properly in its parent.

```
function PaperComponent(props: PaperProps) { 
// PaperProps is an import from '@material-ui/core'
    return (
        <Paper {...props} style={{ margin: 0, maxHeight: '100%' }} />
    );
}
```

Be sure to place this function **outside of the rendering component.** Otherwise, every time the state changes, your dialog contents will be remounted. This was bad for me because I was using an Autocomplete field in the dialog, and every time I selected an option and did something with the `onChange()`, the text input would disappear. Changing the function scope fixed this problem.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but this doesnt make the component draggable @April

Comment: Nice answer, this is a good solution for a Dialog you'd want to minimise to a smaller version (e.g. a video playing) while continuing to interact with the rest of the document. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

disabling enforce focus can also disturb the origin and position
Use disableAutoFocus

```
<Dialog
    hideBackdrop={true}
    disableBackdropClick
    disableAutoFocus
    ...
>
    ....
</Dialog>
```